# How to keep static state between nunit multiple test assemblies execution

Tags: c#, database, nunit, integration-testing

I have a base class that creates some test databases and then those are used by the tests in multiple assemblies. Those tests are methods in classes that inherits from this base class.

However, it seems that when the runner changes to another assembly the base class recreates again the test databases, losing considerable time.

Is there a way to save this state between assemblies in NUnit?

Thanks.

Comment: Why is it generating the Databases again? Usually DB setup code works to the tune of "If Database does not exist, create Database. Else, do nothing."

Comment: Because the database name is dynamic when first executed but it has to be maintained for all the tests run. Its dynamic at first because other programmers can execute tests too and has to be a different database.

Comment: I can't check if the database exists because I don't know the name. NUnit initializes the static properties again when switching assembly.

Comment: Sounds like they should get the DB name from a configuration/installation setting, but als use the same default. Clearly they are intended to cooperate, so if they should be sharing a existing DB should be a configuration setting.

Comment: Well, if NUnit doesnt have a feature to store values between assemblies, as you said, I'll have to save the name in a file or in another external storage other than memory.